# Redirect all url using .htaccess except one dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all url from `http` to `https`, this works just fine for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now i want to add one exception to this rule, i.e whenever a user request the following dynamic url (the last string is dynamically generated) it should not apply force `https` redirect.

```
sub.domian.dev/api/v/1/download/zip/token/8397298347ksjdnkjasdn0394834
```

I tried this rule which does not work.

```
#url to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v/1$
```

Can someone give me the pointer on how to go with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# except /api/v/1/ requests redirect everything else to https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+api/v/1/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, i don't want `/api/v/1/` to be force http, the user should be able to access using `http` or `https` for this URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v/1/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```